# How to mirror auto increment value and combine with value in another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an auto increment column `id` in a table, this works fine but I am trying to create an `order_id` column that combines the `account_id` of a user with the auto increment value of `id`.

So the values inside `order_id` look for example like this:

```
33.1000
52.1001
69.1002
Etc
```

Where the number before the dot is the `account_id` and the number after is the auto incremented value of `id`.

How can I do this?

Similar answers I found are for another database language or are questions with dead links.

I've tried immediatly updating the database after an insert using PHP with the last inserted id function `insert_id` but I'm sure this can be done in SQL.

Comment: Neither default value expression nor generated column nor trigger may help. So move insertion logiс into stored procedure or use a view which generates combined value on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the value as:

```
concat(account_id, '.', lpad(id, 4, '0'))
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use this as a generated value or default value for the column.  That gives you two options.

The first is to use a view:

```
create table v_t
    select t.*, concat(account_id, '.', lpad(id, 4, '0')) as order_id
    from t;
```

Or to set the value using a trigger.

Comment: I've tried the following trigger: `UPDATE orders SET NEW.order_id = CONCAT(NEW.account_id, '.', NEW.ID)` as both a `BEFORE INSERT` and `AFTER INSERT` but I keep getting this error: `Can't update table 'orders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: @twan . . . You don't use `update` in a trigger.  You just set the value:  `set new.order_id = concat(new.account_id, '.', lpad(new.id, 4, '0'))`.

Comment: thanks lol this is the first time I am using a trigger. Does this mean I have to get the last inserted id and insert that to the id table for every query I do? Because if I leave it empty the numbers after the dot just say `0000` while the `id` column shows the correct auto incremented value.